# Observable TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am really new at this and I don't understand something.

I have a CalendarService in which I have a method getYear(id: string).
In my Year model looks like this

```
export class Year {
    id: string;
    number: Number;
    months: Month[];
    weeks: Week[];
}
```

What I need is to get data from Months[] (name, numberOfDays, etc.).

This is how my service looks:

```
@Injectable()
export class CalendarService {
  endPoint: string;
  private _calendarUrl = '/api/mycalendar';

  months: Month[];
  year: Date;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getYear(id: string): Observable<Year> {
    return this.http.get(this._calendarUrl + '?id=' + id)._catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getYears() {
    return this.http.get(this._calendarUrl)
                     .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                    ._catch(this.handleError);

  }

  getMonths(yearId: string) {
    // get year from db
    const year =  this.getYear(yearId); 
    
   // access months
    this.months = year.
  }


  private handleError(error: any) {
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.log(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }

}
```

Comment: so , what do you want to acheive [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _"I don't understand somehting."_ You did not say what you do not understand. What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@Injectable()
export class CalendarService {
  endPoint: string;
  private _calendarUrl = '/api/mycalendar';

  months: Month[];
  year: Date;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getYear(id: string): Observable<Year> {
    return this.http.get(this._calendarUrl + '?id=' + id)._catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getYears() {
    return this.http.get(this._calendarUrl)
                     .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                    ._catch(this.handleError);

  }

// in here you need to do the api call and subscribe for the response.
  getMonths(yearId: string) {
    const year =  this.getYear(yearId).subscribe((response) => {
          this.months = response.
     }); 
  }


  private handleError(error: any) {
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.log(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getYear` `http` call returns an `observable`. So

You need to `subscribe` to `observable`

```
getMonths(yearId: string) {
    const year =  this.getYear(yearId).subscribe((response) => {
          this.months = response.months // or response.data.months
     });  

}
```

Comment: @Teodora Malec, check this? any help needed?